# Xampp vhost cannot load the virtualhost without port number

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

I am not sure if this is a repost but I couldn't find a solution.
I have an application setup in my local environment which the name I added in my hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) as follows,

`127.0.0.1 skeletonpage.lk`

Also I added a record in httpd-vhosts.conf as below.

`<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/skeleton/public"
    ServerName skeletonpage.lk
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/skeleton/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

When I run the application on browser I can only load the homepage with the port number tagged with the site name. Ex: http://skeletonpage.lk:83/

I have both XAMPP and WAMP in my machine and my site runs in XAMPP for which the port 83 is given, If I remove :83 it loads the homepage of wamp server which has port 80.

I tried removing and modifying above code snippet but still cant get rid of port 83. I know this is something simple, but would be glad if someone can help.

I modified as `<VirtualHost *:83> also <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:83>` and restarted XAMPP also modified `NameVirtualHost *:83` but no use.

Comment: Whats the location of httpd-vhosts.conf that you edited? I can't even load the page, always get 500 internal error, even on `http://localhost` after I modify the `/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf `

Comment: hi @3zzy , location of the file is `/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` as you mentioned, however be careful when you edit the file, if there are typos the page wont load, so better check the file again and restart XAMPP , might be the solution for you.

Comment: I've spent hours on this, but can't get it to work. can you please share your conf file?

Comment: I am new here, so don't know how to share files, any suggestions?

Comment: `
NameVirtualHost *:83

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
  </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/skeleton/public"
    ServerName skeletonpage.lk
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/skeleton/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
`

Comment: Which version are you on? I'm on Xampp 3.2.2 and if I paste the above, apache won't start :(

Comment: I don't think version is the problem, its Xampp 1.8.3 for me

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: nope, it didn't. I'm still stuck.